# Error : "No document to update " in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im using cloudFirestore as the database and i want to update a Field that lives in a document.
collection :users.
document:user.
field:website.

so for that i did like so :

```
db.doc('/users/user').update({website:'user.com'});
```

but iam getting this Error :

> No document to update: projects/social-app-12282/databases/(default)/documents/users/user'

Can someone tell me wht this happen,thank you in advance

**Edit:**
you can see here that i have a docment called user
[image]

Comment: The error message is saying you have no document called "/users/user".  Please edit the question to explain why you think this statement of error is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you to update a document in Firestore, the structure of the update is a little bit different in relation to yours. As per the documentation - accessible [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data) - you need to select the collection and then, the document you want to update. The code would be something like the below one:

```
var usersRef = db.collection("users").doc("user");

// Set the "user" field of the city 'DC'
return usersRef.update({
    "website": "user.com"
})
.then(function() {
    console.log("Document successfully updated!");
})
.catch(function(error) {
    // The document probably doesn't exist.
    console.error("Error updating document: ", error);
});
```

A simplified version would be:

```
db.collection("users").doc("user").update({
    "website": "user.com"
})
.then(function() {
    console.log("Document successfully updated!");
});
```

**While this is untested code**, I believe it should help you with understanding on how to update the values and as a starting point. You can get more examples from the official documentation as well.

Comment: this is very strange  the same error again but Believe me i create two  documents with the same  name and the result is  the second one updated but the first one not updated !!

Comment: So, after using this code, one of the documents is updated and the other doesn't? Do they have the same name? If so, this could be causing the issue.

Comment: No,Also i tried to update just one doument but it doesn't updated ,still not working.

Comment: and Note that,what i did is when a user signup  a document automatically created,and the field that Im trying to update is not exist in the document,and as far i know even it is not exist it will be created !

Comment: Could you please give it a try replacing `update` to `set`? If the field doesn't exist, it needs to be created and `set` will either create if it doesn't exist or update if does.

Comment: yes i tried that it set a new document with the same name but the old one still as it is

Comment: I would recommend you to delete the old document and go with the new one, if it created with the `website` field. Probably there was an issue with the name, like some broken character, hidden character or something, due to the fact that apparently the names are the same.

Comment: you are right man i found that i have an issue with the name of the document which starts with a <space>,and for that the error it says no document to update,hhh so the error was right and Im stupid,anyway thank you a lot for the help appreciate that.

Comment: Hi @Salah glad to hear you found out and that I could help you! :)